Group ID or split to instances according to similar normal orientation
What is the most consistent way to create IDs based on similar normal orientations—not just according to Z rotation, as in my example? The result should be an ascending ID row (e.g., 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...). My example is a naive approach, as I am currently struggling with this.
I need to avoid merging by distance and splitting by edge angle, as some faces with the same normal cannot be merged to the same mesh island.
The ID or grouping based on normal similarity could be specified using an epsilon value.
Thank you!




Do you want to avoid the colors changing while you rotate the geometry?

This is probably not as important, but would be good to know this  as well for sure.

What is important then? It seems you already have a solution for your problem.

Some islands were flat before triangulation (there might be some very small delta differences), but triangles that belonged there are not considered in the same group. My example leads to not ascending ID row. I would like it use in the repeat zone later avoiding the splitting to instances (takes some time in many objects counts). + My example thakes only the Z rotation in to the account. When I tried to involve another axis the result was very unreliable.

Do you mean "similar normal" or similar roof slope? (The cone, for instance, has wildly varying normals (it will never be grouped together by "similar normals"), but it can be grouped together by slope.  If by slope, then you will need to sort also by island, or any roof of anywhere would mix in. So, you probably need to specify "exactly" the desired grouping/sorting. ----- For instance, if you connect the normal to the viewer, you will view exactly the grouping by similar normals. Will that satisfy?

if an island is flat before triangulation, then it is also flat after triangulation. If triangulation dramatically changes shape then you should use "Fixed" method as it's the one used internally. If your problem is about recovering original normal of an ngon, then state it this way, as it's different than what you asked. In particular, a parallelized algorithm converting a normal to a group ID will not grant consistency for a very simple logical reason: Imagine you convert 1-dimensional coordinate to a group ID. As things move through that dimension they will flip their group ID=inconsistent

@Daniel Möller, The cone purpose only was to show the other than Z rotation grouping should differ as well. Cone should never be grouped. When you rotate the view the cone sides do not have the same slope. Generaly saying I want to achieve something similar to like I would split the roof by edge angle, but as I said this does not work as there might be situations that in one slope are two mesh islands that do not share vertices to be merged together. The normals view was my first thought I just was not able group based on these colors + some colors seems to be identical, is there enough info?

@MarkusvonBroady, triangulation was just way I thought will simplify the question. The task with the solution (that is not consistent as it looks - different splits in rare occasions when I rotate base object in the edit mode and I need it to be split same all the time) is here, the normals should be perfect, but I am not a math person at all and not sure what is 100% perfect... So the thing I want to achieve is not possible?

your approach is flawed because you can't expect even 2D faces (pointing up) to have the exact same normal. And once you accept the normals differ slightly, they may end up in separate buckets.

Yest that is my problem I thought might have a solution. The vector rotate there had a reason to stabilize that a bit by alignment to mean, not sure it is viable and still how to involve other axis than Z only in a proper way? https://i.imgur.com/YcetUew.jpeg Thanks Markus

I don't understand what you mean. You want to achieve split but the problem is not merging? What is the relation?

The relation is that the problem could be very simple if the one slope segment could be split into one mesh island. (Merge all the roof by small distance and split by edge angle) Unfortunately in this image you can see not all is mergeable. For that reason I need to identify the one segment slope by the normal similarity ID and then do some workaround to merge it in to one Ngon. image

You can try to sort by:
Normal -> Vector Math (snap) -> Separate XYZ -> Sum 100x + 10y + z

stability stil minor problems (as Markus mentioned about different buckets above) but more axis involved at least, thanks Daniel

@filanek, thinking further, I think 100(x+2) + 10(y+1) + z would be a little better. The idea is not let the values of each axis affect another axis.

for the sum you can use dot product <100, 10, 1>, no need to separate then.

seems to me with the repeat zone it could lead to the result I am after, but this is something I would like to avoid and I do not like I cannot estimate the amount of the iterations here...;( https://i.imgur.com/0tqkAyM.jpeg

the timing is horrible https://i.imgur.com/fheEkiO.jpeg plus is ascending id row + custom epsilon

Not sure yet, but this seems to work at this tired moment...

